# "cmath: No such file or directory" when compiled with GCC

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc

I wrote the simple program in **linux ubuntu**, when I use g++ there is no error but when I use **gcc** I see this error:

```
test.c:1:17: fatal error: cmath: No such file or directory  #include <cmath>
```

Note : "as a matter of fact I see this error in compiling the package, I thought it might be related to gcc library which is not set to linux environment, so I wrote the simple program to determine the error clearly and whitout dependency!"
so the program should compile with gcc so that I can over come the main problem.
I khow that I can use math.h instead of cmath, but the packege used the cmath!
this is the simple program:

```
   /*test.c*/
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
        double sinx =   sin(3.14/3);
cout<< "sinx= " << sinx;

return 0;
}
```

here is cmath pathes:

```
root@geant4:/# find -name cmath
./opt/root5.32.00/cint/cint/include/cmath
./app/gcc/4.8.0/include/c++/4.8.0/ext/cmath
./app/gcc/4.8.0/include/c++/4.8.0/cmath
./app/gcc/4.8.0/include/c++/4.8.0/tr1/cmath
./usr/include/boost/compatibility/cpp_c_headers/cmath
./usr/include/boost/tr1/tr1/cmath
./usr/include/c++/4.5/cmath
./usr/include/c++/4.5/tr1_impl/cmath
./usr/include/c++/4.5/tr1/cmath
./usr/include/c++/4.6/cmath
./usr/include/c++/4.6/tr1/cmath
./usr/share/gccxml-0.9/GCC/2.95/cmath
./gcc-build/gcc-4.8.0/stage1-i686-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/ext/cmath
./gcc-build/gcc-4.8.0/stage1-i686-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/cmath
./gcc-build/gcc-4.8.0/stage1-i686-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/tr1/cmath
./gcc-build/gcc-4.8.0/i686-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/ext/cmath
./gcc-build/gcc-4.8.0/i686-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/cmath
./gcc-build/gcc-4.8.0/i686-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/tr1/cmath
./gcc-build/gcc-4.8.0/libstdc++-v3/include/ext/cmath
./gcc-build/gcc-4.8.0/libstdc++-v3/include/c/cmath
./gcc-build/gcc-4.8.0/libstdc++-v3/include/c_global/cmath
./gcc-build/gcc-4.8.0/libstdc++-v3/include/c_std/cmath
./gcc-build/gcc-4.8.0/libstdc++-v3/include/tr1/cmath
./gcc-build/gcc-4.8.0/libstdc++-v3/testsuite/26_numerics/headers/cmath
./gcc-build/gcc-4.8.0/libstdc++-v3/testsuite/tr1/8_c_compatibility/cmath
./gcc-build/gcc-4.8.0/prev-i686-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/ext/cmath
./gcc-build/gcc-4.8.0/prev-i686-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/cmath
./gcc-build/gcc-4.8.0/prev-i686-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/tr1/cmath
```

and after installing gcc-4.8 I did this instruction:

```
root@geant4:~/Desktop# update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /app/gcc/4.8.0/bin/gcc 40 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /app/gcc/4.8.0/bin/g++

root@geant4:~/Desktop#update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /app/gcc/4.8.0/bin/gcc 60 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /app/gcc/4.8.0/bin/g++
root@geant4:~/Desktop# update-alternatives --config gcc
```

to make gcc-4.8 my default gcc.

now

```
root@geant4:~/Desktop# gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.8.0
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

as a matter of fact I wrote the main problem in https://askubuntu.com/questions/309195/cmath-no-such-file-or-directory-include-cmath

please help me
I don`t know what to do.
thanks

Comment: +1 for good question and simplifying the code to determine the error clearly.

Comment: cmath is for C++, use math.h for C, if file is ends with .c but it's clearly and C++ file, change the ending.

Answer (score 7):

Some basics::

```
GCC:: GNU Compiler Collection
G++:: GNU C++ Compiler
```

**Both are drivers which calls the compilers as needed.**

Clearing your doubt::

The problem with `GCC` is that it doesn't links in the **std C++ libraries** by default as `G++` does. `GCC` is just a front-end. The actual compiler is `cc1plus.` So it is always advisable to use `G++` when compiling C++ files. The result can be same with both `GCC` and `G++` if you do know the exact arguments to link them. You may find this [link](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_54.html) helpful.

But if you still want to use `GCC`, use it with linker-option `-lstdc++` at the end of the command. This linker-option is added by default when you use `G++`. You can verify this by compiling your code using `GCC` with `-###` option and it will show you that `-lstdc++` option is missing.

Comment: I used gcc with the option `-lstdc++` but it didn`t work! the error remained.I wrote this command: `gcc test.c -lstdc++`

Comment: Can you post the command you have used? Also, try g++ with -v option, it will show you all the commands and options. You can deduce the correct from there.

Comment: `gcc test.c -lstdc++ `  `root@geant4:~/Desktop# g++ -v`
Using built-in specs.  
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/app/gcc/4.8.0/libexec/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.8.0/lto-wrapper
Target: i686-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: ./configure --prefix=/app/gcc/4.8.0
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.0 (GCC)

Comment: Rename your file to "test.cpp". GCC calls the respective compiler by seeing the extension of the file.

Comment: @alirezayousefi the build fails at the compilation stage, not the linking stage, so adding `-lstdc++` won't happen. the problem is, that g++ has other include paths as gcc - and "cmath" being a *c++* header is only searched when the program is compiled as C++

Comment: thank you for answering , it works with g++ but as I mentioned in Note , I asked this question because I see the same error in my main works in installing the _wfconvert_ package in linux ubuntu. this is the main problem  http://askubuntu.com/questions/309195/cmath-no-such-file-or-directory-include-cmath

Comment: That's why I gave you that "Some Basics" part in my soln. GCC will invoke compilers "cc1" for C and "cc1plus" for C++ which it decides on after seeing the file extension. But G++ always treat both *.c & *.cpp as C++ files. And why are exactly not using G++? Is there any specific reason?

Comment: yes there is, see this link that is my main problem.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/309195/cmath-no-such-file-or-directory-include-cmath

Comment: If your main problem is that, then may be you should wait for a soln there and shouldn't start posting your question everywhere.

Comment: yes you are right, I mentioned it in my first question "NOTE:" ! I did that and I wait for answer there but the  question here is some how simpler and the error is the same with that, maybe this solution help to answer of that. thanks for your comments

Answer (score 3):

Compile C++ source files with g++, not gcc.